# Mockito test with ArgumentCaptor failing from time to time

Tags: mockito, argumentcaptor

I am using Java 17, Spring Boot 2.7.5 (spring-boot-starter-test is introducing JUnit Jupiter and Mockito to my project). Full project code (WIP) is here: https://github.com/Tonypsilon/bmm.backend

I have a method that I want to test:

```
    public void verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub(@NonNull String username, @NonNull Set<Long> clubIds) {
        if (clubIds.stream()
                .map(clubAdminService::getAdminsOfClub)
                .flatMap(Set::stream)
                .noneMatch(username::equals)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("...");
        }
    }
```

The method `getAdminsOfClub` returns a Set of Strings. Here is my test for the success case:

```
    @Test
    void testVerifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClubSuccess() {
        String username = "username";
        Set<Long> clubIds = Set.of(1L, 2L);
        when(clubAdminService.getAdminsOfClub(1L)).thenReturn(Set.of("some user", "another user"));
        when(clubAdminService.getAdminsOfClub(2L)).thenReturn(Set.of("username", "some user"));

        ArgumentCaptor<Long> clubIdArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Long.class);
        authorizationService.verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub(username, clubIds);
        verify(clubAdminService, times(2)).getAdminsOfClub(clubIdArgumentCaptor.capture());
        assertThat(clubIdArgumentCaptor.getAllValues()).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(1L, 2L);
    }
```

The test is passing about 80% of the times I run it with Eclipse. Until now, it passed of the runs in Intellij IDEA. Note that Eclipse somehow needs about half as much time for test execution.
When it fails, this is the stack trace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooFewActualInvocations: 
clubAdminService.getAdminsOfClub(
    <Capturing argument>
);
Wanted 2 times:
-> at de.tonypsilon.bmm.backend.security.rnr.service.AuthorizationServiceTest.testVerifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClubSuccess(AuthorizationServiceTest.java:39)
But was 1 time:
-> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)

    at de.tonypsilon.bmm.backend.security.rnr.service.AuthorizationServiceTest.testVerifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClubSuccess(AuthorizationServiceTest.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

I thought it might be related to the test cases in general executing very fast (~0,01s), so maybe something is happening there in parallel where something finishes before it should. But I am not sure about the internals and I wouldn't expect such a behaviour.

So my next thought would be that I am using ArgumentCaptor in the wrong way, as I am not very experienced with it. I tried to read up about it but couldn't find information helping me with my specific case. Is anyone able to help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side question: why do you care that the `getAdminsOfClub` method is called in the first place? You are interested in the final result, you (usually) don't care which methods were called to get to the result. And since your implementation uses short-circuiting logic, you may end up with a variable number of calls to the method. I don't think this verification should really be part of the test and is an implementation details that's better to ignore (i.e. "black box testing")

Comment: That could quickly become philosophical, I think ;-) 
I like unit tests to be white-box tests.  In this specific case, it's void, so I don't get anything back, but still I want to avoid that n empty implementation would pass the test. The "official" service that tells if someone is authorized as a club admin for a club is the ClubAdminService, so I make sure, that this official instance is "asked for permission", so to say. I would go for blackbox tests on the level of SpringBootTest or WebMvcTest. But that's all just my (pretty inexperienced) take on it, I will constantly try to improve :-)

Comment: The big disadvantage I see with this approach is that you cannot change the implementation without also touching your tests. This removes a layer of safety, because if you have to change both at the same time, how do you know that the behavior hasn't changed as well? Ideally, internal restructuring of the implementation shouldn't have any effect on tests. There are probably arguments for the other approach too; just wanted to share my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely related to the input set. Since HashSet has no deterministic order, it will either arrive at the subject method as `[1, 2]` or `[2, 1]`.

That verification step will fail if it arrives as `[2, 1]` because streams are optimized to fail fast, and since it finds "username" in the first iteration it won't make the second attempt.

The above should be easy to verify by adding a `System.out.println(clubIds)` at the start of the `verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub` method and checking that the test fails every time it prints `[2, 1]`.

```java
public void verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub(@NonNull String username, @NonNull Set<Long> clubIds) {
    System.out.println(clubIds);
    // ...
}
```

If that's the case, it's also likely that if you replace the HashSet with a TreeSet, the test will pass 100% of the time (not implying this should be the solution, but more like a proof of concept).

```java
// Example
Set<Long> clubIds = new TreeSet<>(List.of(1L, 2L));
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the issue. To quote from Javadoc of noneMatch: "May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result."

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an exact answer to your question, but I would suggest to split up this test into multiple smaller ones:

- test that the returns of `getAdminsOfClub` works for no occurence of the admin
- test that the returns of `getAdminsOfClub` works for one occurence of the admin
- test that the returns of `getAdminsOfClub` works for multiple occurences of the admin
- test that the `getAdminsOfClub` method is invoked once for each club

This way you would not have to use the `ArgumentCaptor`at all:

```java
@Test
void verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub_no_admin() {
  when(clubAdminService.getAdminsOfClub(anyLong()))
      .thenReturn(Set.of("some user", "another user"));
  assertThrows(
      AccessDeniedException.class,
      ()->authorizationService.verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub("userName", Set.of(1L)),
      "..."
  );
}

@Test
void verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub_1_admin() {
  when(clubAdminService.getAdminsOfClub(anyLong()))
    .thenReturn(Set.of("userName", "another user"), Set.of("some user", "another user"));
  assertDoesNotThrow(
      ()->authorizationService.verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub("userName", Set.of(1L, 47L))
  );
}

@Test
void verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub_2_admins() {
  when(clubAdminService.getAdminsOfClub(anyLong()))
      .thenReturn(Set.of("userName", "another user"), Set.of("some user", "userName"));

  assertDoesNotThrow(
      ()->authorizationService.verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub("userName", Set.of(1L, 47L))
  );
}

@Test
void verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub_calls_getAdminsOfClub_for_each_club() {
  assertThrows(
      AccessDeniedException.class,
      ()->authorizationService.verifyUserIsClubAdminOfAnyClub("userName", Set.of(1L, 42L)),
      "..."
  );
  verify(clubAdminService).getAdminsOfClub(1L);
  verify(clubAdminService).getAdminsOfClub(42L);
}
```

The third parameter of `assertThrows` is the expected message. I hope that you have not `"..."` as message literally.

If the exception message is dynamic I would just not specify the third parameter in the test - only test that if it's crucial for the programs logic (which shouldn't be the case).